# Phonegap IOS APP - The Video is thumbnail not showing up

Tags: ios, html, cordova, html5-video

[image]
[image]

Thumbnail is not showing up although I made sure that the poster is accessible and present using the simulator safari
N.B: This tag was copied from the inspecting the simulator html

```
<video controls="" class="thumb" width="100%">
                        <source src="file://localhost/Users/gharris/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FF02B808-B27C-4FEC-A1D1-69D07521C947/Documents/BnS/assets/c7984b8a-3630-6f51-9d38-ff00001222dd.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="file://localhost/Users/gharris/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FF02B808-B27C-4FEC-A1D1-69D07521C947/Documents/BnS/assets/cd984b8a-3630-6f51-9d38-ff00001222dd.jpg" preload="auto">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the source tag, when i turned it into this format it works

```
<video controls="" class="thumb" width="100%" src="file://localhost/Users/gharris/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FF02B808-B27C-4FEC-A1D1-69D07521C947/Documents/BnS/assets/c7984b8a-3630-6f51-9d38-ff00001222dd.mp4" type="video/mp4" poster="file://localhost/Users/gharris/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/FF02B808-B27C-4FEC-A1D1-69D07521C947/Documents/BnS/assets/cd984b8a-3630-6f51-9d38-ff00001222dd.jpg" preload="auto">
</video>
```

so simply remove this source tag and copy the attributes directly to the video tag